# Parallax- Having images move faster than background

Tags: css

I have looked all over for this and cannot find a tutorial or anything to help create it.

I am looking to do something like [this site](http://www.czk.fr/)

If you see on the left the text Mar is scrolling faster than the background image. Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can learn how that is done.

Answer (score 0):

The site you are reffering to uses only JavaScript for making all the animations. Using this technique has some andvanteges and disadvanteges (for example you can't use hardware-acceleration).

But as you have used [css](/questions/tagged/css) as your only tag I will lead you to a pure css solution:

At first you should read something about 3D-transformations in CSS3. The reason for this is, that you will move the things that has to move slower far away in the background. This will have the side effect, that they appear to be smaller. This problem can be resolved be using `zoom` in CSS.
If [this](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/) is exactly what you wan't [here](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) is a good tutorial on how to do this.

Tipp: When you wan't to learn new things it's always a good practice looking what other people have done. This is very easy in webdesign because you can look at other peoples sourcecode :-)

Comment: This is just a short summary of what you have to do because you wanted to be lead *in the right direction*. If you need any further help, then just ask :-)